# Custom Product Attribute not applying in Promo Rules

Tags: catalog-price-rules, promotions, custom-attributes

I have a custom attribute set for my products named "**item_category**". I have set  Use for Promo Rule Conditions to yes for the attribute, and it is displayed in the catalog rule as well.

But the problem is, Even if I set a condition with the value(For ex.**item_category** is ABCD) and there is/are products with the attribute value(i.e. products whose **item_category** attribute value is "**ABCD**"), The rule does not get applied.

I have tried with built-in attribute category, If I set it to some existing category id. The rule gets triggered, but not with custom product attributes.

**Edit1**

I have googled for two days now, but no results. This is a feature supported by Magento itself, as I understand. Is it some kind of bug?

any help would be much appreciated.

If this helps:

I found the below lines for condition in the catalogrule table

1) This condition works for adding discount for all the products of category 232

```
'a:7:{s:4:"type";s:34:"catalogrule/rule_condition_combine";s:9:"attribute";N;s:8:"operator";N;s:5:"value";s:1:"1";s:18:"is_value_processed";N;s:10:"aggregator";s:3:"all";s:10:"conditions";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:"type";s:34:"catalogrule/rule_condition_product";s:9:"attribute";s:12:"category_ids";s:8:"operator";s:2:"==";s:5:"value";s:3:"232";s:18:"is_value_processed";b:0;}}}'
```

2) This condition is where I am trying to set the discount for products which have their attribute item_category custom value to MMRJ3

```
'a:7:{s:4:"type";s:34:"catalogrule/rule_condition_combine";s:9:"attribute";N;s:8:"operator";N;s:5:"value";s:1:"1";s:18:"is_value_processed";N;s:10:"aggregator";s:3:"all";s:10:"conditions";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:"type";s:34:"catalogrule/rule_condition_product";s:9:"attribute";s:12:"category_ids";s:8:"operator";s:2:"==";s:5:"value";s:3:"232";s:18:"is_value_processed";b:0;}}}'
```

Need some help guys!

Comment: This was a very dumb thing, there was a space in the items custom attribute value, for which the price rule was not applying.